# Finding the equation of reflected ray for given ray

Tags: vectors, 3d

A ray is sent along the line $\frac{x-0}{2}=\frac{y-2}{2}=\frac{z-1}{0}$ and is reflected by the plane $x=0$ at point $A$. Find the coordinates of $A$ and equation of the reflected ray.

I found coordinates of point $A$ as $(0,2,1)$. Could someone now help me with the concept of finding reflected ray in $3$-D?

Comment: @amd My bad. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: This stuff is much easier if you use vector algebra. In particular, define the ray as $$\vec{v}(t) = \vec{v}_0 + t \hat{v}_n$$where $\hat{v}_n$ is an unit vector, and the plane using its normal vector $\hat{n}$ and signed distance from origin $d$. This way, after you find the point $\vec{v}(t)$ where the ray intersects the plane, it is very easy to compute the new ray. (This also extends to other surfaces, where the hard part is to find the intersection point. When the surface normal is known at the intersection point, the reflected ray is computed the same way.)

Comment: ... because the reflected unit direction vector $\hat{v}_n^,$ is $$\hat{v}_n - 2 \hat{n} (\hat{n} \cdot \hat{v}_n)$$(although I don't offhand remember when/whether it is guaranteed to be of unit length).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the incident ray is coming from the negative side of the plane $x=0$.

Parametric equation of incident ray is
$$\mathbf{r}(t)=(0,2,1)+t(2,2,0)$$
where $t\in (-\infty,0]$.

The incident ray passes through $(0,2,1)$ which is on the reflecting plane.  That's the point of incidence.

The reflected ray is just simply reverse the $x$-component of the tangent vector.

So the reflected ray is
$$\mathbf{r}(t)=(0,2,1)+t(-2,2,0)$$
where $t\in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Could you explain, "The reflected ray is just simply reverse the x-component of the tangent vector."?

Comment: The unit normal vector is $\mathbf{n}=(-1,0,0)$.  So $\mathbf{k}^i \cdot \mathbf{n}=-\mathbf{k}^r \cdot \mathbf{n} \implies k^i_x=-k^r_x$ and no change in directions of other components ($\mathbf{k}^i \times \mathbf{n}=\mathbf{k}^r \times \mathbf{n}$).  That is $\mathbf{k}^i=(2,2,0)$ and $\mathbf{k}^r=(-2,2,0)$.

Comment: @Mathgeek: If it matters at all, using the notation in my comment to the question, $\hat{v}_n = (\sqrt{1/2}, \sqrt{1/2}, 0)$, $\hat{n}=(-1,0,0)$, so $$\hat{v}_n^, = \hat{v}_n - 2 \hat{n} ( \hat{n} \cdot \hat{v}_n ) = \hat{v}_n - 2 \hat{n} (-\sqrt{1/2}+0+0) = (\sqrt{1/2}, \sqrt{1/2}, 0) - (-2 \sqrt{1/2}, 0, 0) = (-\sqrt{1/2}, \sqrt{1/2}, 0)$$, which matches this answer by Ng Chung Tak (if we ignore the scaling factor, my vectors being of unit length).